# jquery validate - input with two exact lengths

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate an input which can have either 8 or 11 characters. I don't believe there's a method existing.

I have eight different inputs to validate in a form. I extend the validate() method and assign rules and showErrors for the inputs. When the user clicks Save, I call $form.valid() to validate and display error messages. One way is to add a new rule to the jquery validate file. I wonder if there's another way like validating in the file where I trigger this event.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what to ask and how. HINT: Show code and effort - thousands of REGEX to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the form on `submit` you can do it like this for example.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input class="to-validate" name="someInput" type="text" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    var inputValueLength = $("input.to-validate", $(this)).val().length;

    if( inputValueLength != 8 && inputValueLength != 11 ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // do somthing here, like display an error message

        return false;
    }
});
```

---

You can even validate an input directly on change too:

```
$("input.to-validate").change(function() {
    var inputValueLength = $(this).val().length;

    if( inputValueLength != 8 && inputValueLength != 11 ) {
        // do somthing here, like display an error message
    }
});
```