# jQuery Validate rangelength with two colliding ranges

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Format A: `01234567890123456` (17 characters)
Format B: `01234567890123456789012` (23 characters)

In my scenario both 17 and 23 is accepted, neither less or more, nor in-between.

So,

- 2 characters is incorrect
- 16 characters is incorrect
- 17 characters is **CORRECT**
- 18 characters is incorrect
- 21 characters is incorrect
- 23 characters is **CORRECT**
- 23+ characters is incorrect

The typical [`rangelength` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rangelength-method/) doesn't comply with this sort of conditions.

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    national_id: {
      required: true,
      rangelength: [17, 23]
    }
  }
});
```

Because it can accept 18/19/20/21/22 as correct - which should be wrong.

How can I achieve such sort of `rangelength` validation using [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin?

PS: I know I can do something easy like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38056669/1743124), but can we do such thing using jQuery Validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use [the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to create your own custom rule.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlengths", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || (value.length == params[0] || value.length == params[1]);
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please only enter {0} or {1} characters"));
```

Declared:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        national_id: {
            required: true,
            exactlengths: [17, 23] ....
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/L5ff6jqw/](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ff6jqw/)

Comment: Worked like a charm. That's the missing part. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a method in additional.js which will validate a range and also allow the particular numbers :

```
 $.validator.addMethod(
    "ranges_and_single",
     function(value, element, ranges) {
        var allowMeToo = false;
        var valid = false;
        console.log(this.optional(element));
        for(var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
            if(ranges[i].length == 1) { 
                if(value == ranges[i][0])
                {
                    allowMeToo = true;
                }
            }
            if(allowMeToo)
            {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
            else if(value >= ranges[i][0] && (value <= ranges[i][1] || allowMeToo )) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return this.optional(element) || valid;
    },
    "Please enter the value in the ranges or perticular number"
 );
```

eg.

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    fieldName: {
      ranges_and_single:[ [2, 5], [7], [10, 15], [17], [25] ],
    //It will allow 2, 3, 4, 5 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17 and 25
    }
  }
});
```